# How to disable or enable programmaticaly layout_behavior added by default in the layout.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-support-design

I'm using the android support design library in my project. Here is my layout.xml with DrawerLayout, CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout, ToolBar and NavigationView. In fact, my Activity contains a NavigationDrawer and the FrameLayout @+id/container is the place where FragmentManager adds/replaces Fragment. My problem is that I have one Fragment which needs app:layout_behavior as attribute for this container FrameLayout, and an another fragment which doesn't need it. My need is to enable this behavior when the first fragment is the content of the container and to disable it in case of the another Fragment. How can I do that ?

My activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hhsociete.mybootstrap.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!-- The ActionBar -->
            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```